# How to efficiently prepare for a 2km run

Tags: running

so I run quite a lot, in the past 3 months I also started working out, so I reduced the number of my runs to 3-4 a week, but it's usually distances ranging from 5 to 20 km. There is this local competition for a best 2km time and I'd like to win it but I never ran short distances like this before. So if any of you have some specific advice, I would be very grateful, I have about a week to prepare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am no athletics trainer whatsoever, so this is from my personal experience as a footballer who only occasionally takes part in a run.

In the next few days, train only on short distances with high pace. That can be anything from 1 km at full pace to a 5 km with intervals. Running anything more than 5 km makes no sense anymore. Your stamina is fine and should be the basis of a good performance.

Train until two days before the race, after that, only a bit of jogging (low pace, small distance) if you feel like to. You should not feel anything from training activities on the day of the race.

During the race, I think that you're best shot is to use your endurance training in your favor. So, try to get the pace up right from the beginning. Force the "sprinters" to put in enough effort right from the start to prevent them from getting a slow first kilometer and getting beat in a ferocious final kilometer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I should have specified that I will be running on my own and be timed separately as will everyone else taking part in the competition.

Comment: Also, if I were to do 5km with intervals, what pace would you suggest for the interval and what pace for the rest period?

Comment: do the intervals with 80%-90% of your max. heartrate. The slow ones try to get in your aerobe zone or at least the transit zone. You might try 2min/5min intervals

Answer (score 1):

I honestly believe that you should do some under-distances to work on your speed, because compared to the distances you are used to a 2km run is almost a sprint.

As things stand, you will struggle if you find a fast guy at the end of the race. You might stand no chance in beating him in a sprint.

So - I'd work on some repetitions over a shorter distance (say 500m) at a higher pace than you are used to do your long runs. Even better, try to make them in increasing pace and go hard for the last one. You really need to stimulate your muscles to react for the last sprint.